# Storage get() never returning value in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2

Learning ionic 2, particularly using `Storage`.

So, I just created a blank app:

```
ionic start storagetest blank --v2
```

Following this [the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/storage/):

```
cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage --save
npm install --save @ionic/storage
```

Then, my `app.module.ts` looks like this:

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And then went ahead to `home.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, storage: Storage) {

     storage.ready().then(() => {
       storage.set('name', 'Max');
       storage.get('name').then((val) => {
         console.log('Your name is', val);
       })
     });

  }

}
```

There is nothing in the javascript log. It appears that `get()` is never returning the value. However, `ready()` does work, as I have put a `console.log()` in it.

What is wrong then?

I am running the app on Chrome, Mac OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`storage.set` is asynchronous and returns a promise.So value may not be set when `get().then()` is called. Try:

```
 storage.ready().then(() => {
       storage.set('name', 'Max').then(()=>
       storage.get('name').then((val) => {
         console.log('Your name is', val);
       });
      );
     });
```

You have no error handler in `then` or `catch()` method which is probably why nothing is logged.